# Deriving Transition Matrix of the Embedded Markov Chain given the generator matrix?

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, markov-process, exponential-distribution

**Full Problem:** A continuous-time Markov chain has generator matrix

$$Q=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    -1 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & -2 & 1 \\
    2 & 2 & -4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

(i) Exhibit the transition matrix of the embedded Markov chain.

(ii) Exhibit the holding time parameters for each state.

---

OK, I must be misunderstanding something. I have the following for the embedded chain transition probabilities:

$$P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{q_i}$$

where $q_i$ is the parameters of the exponential length of time that the process stays in i.

The problem is that I know $q_i$ is the minimum with exponential distribution and parameter $\sum_k q_{ik}$.

But when I calculate $P_{11}$ that gives me $-1$ which is impossible..

Obviously there is an error in my thinking but can anyone shine light on what I'm misunderstanding? Thank you greatly in advance.

Comment: I discovered my mistake. The diagonals are always zero. I'll leave this here in case anyone finds themselves equally confused.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "the diagonals are always zero," because  that's not the case either with $Q$ or with the answer to (i).

Comment: No. The diagonals of the transition matrix of the embedded Markov chain are supposed to be zero because there is no self-transition in a continuous state markov chain. 

Also, I don't consider this a duplicate. It is a different method of deriving the transition matrix of the embedded M.C. that does not require diagonalization.

Comment: The only way your readers would understand that would be for you to edit your post to elaborate on these requirements and restrictions.

Comment: Is there a case where transition to the same state is possible in continuous time Markov Chains? My understanding was that you cannot have self-transition trivially explained by the fact that a same state transition is simply the state staying in the starting state for exponentially distributed time.

Comment: It seems like you might be confusing a generator with the transition matrix itself.  I'm not reading anything that distinguishes your question (in its current form) from the duplicate.

Comment: No no. I see where the confusion stems from. The question you linked to mine is asking for $P(t)$ which is the transition function. I was asking how to find the embedded chain transition matrix. I.e. the transition function with 0 waiting time.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/340948/continuous-markov-chains-deriving-the-transition-matrix-from-the-generator-matr ?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed $P_{ij} = \frac{q_{ij}}{q_j}$ for $i\ne j$, so the transition matrix for the embedded Markov chain is
$$
P=\pmatrix{
0&1&0\\
\frac12&0&\frac12\\
\frac12&\frac12&0
}.
$$
The holding time for state $0$ has $\mathsf{Exp}(1)$ distribution since $q_{01}=1$ and $q_{02}=2$. The holding time for state $1$ has $\mathsf{Exp}(2)$ since $q_{10}=q_{12}=1$ and the minimum of two independent exponential random variables is again exponential with rate equal to the sum of the two. A similar argument shows that the holding time for state $2$ has $\mathsf{Exp}(4)$ distribution.