# Infinitesimal generator of Markov chain using numpy

Tags: markov-process, matrix-decomposition, numpy

I am computing the infinitesimal generator of a continuous-time Markov chain from the transition probabilities `p`. I am following the methodology described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/131325/217516), just translated the R code to python/numpy.

```
p = np.array([[0.8,0.2,0],[0.1,0.7,0.2],[0.1,0.1,0.8]]) # probabilities, rows sum to 1
values, vectors = np.linalg.eig(p)
q = vectors@np.diag(np.log(values))@np.linalg.inv(vectors)
print(q)
 [[-0.238  0.273 -0.035]
 [ 0.119 -0.392  0.273]
 [ 0.119  0.119 -0.238]]
```

If `q` contains transition rates, like explained in page 17 [here](https://mast.queensu.ca/~stat455/lecturenotes/set5.pdf), I would expect that given `p[0,2]` is `0`, the corresponding `q[0,2]` should also be 0, but that is not the case.

Is there something wrong with my methodology? or is it my assumption that 0 values in `p` should also correspond to 0 values in `q`?

Comment: Your assumption is tantamount to supposing that matrix multiplication is just component-by-component multiplication, but that's not the case.